# How to minimize a loss function that is dependent on itself through the coefficients?

Tags: optimization, fixed-point-theorems, gradient-descent

For an optimization problem I am solving, I have the following problem.

We have to minimize loss function $f$, which is dependent on a coefficient vector $\theta$, $A$, and $B$. Now $B$ is dependent on the maximum of $f$. I am unsure what kind of algorithm is used. I am guessing some kind of fixed-point algorithm.

An example I'm thinking of would find start with some value for $B$, use gradient descent on $\theta$, and reiterate until some criteria are met. But I hope there is something better.

$\color{magenta}{\star}$ What type of algorithm would be used for such a problem where the function is dependent on coefficients that are dependent on the function itself? And, possibly, what would be the requirements for it to converge?

---

I am fairly sure it is not possible to define a function in the way I did, however maybe someone is familiar with similar problems and could give me a source for functions/ optimization problems like this one.

Comment: Can you provide a detailed, explicit example of the kind of problem you want to solve?

Comment: So I am trying to fit a function $f(t, \theta, A)$ to some data $G(t)$, we try to minimize the criteria $|| f(\theta,A)-G||_p$, where we use either the L1 or L2 norm. Optimizing over $\theta$ is easy as we can use gradient descent (we know the form of $f$, however $A$ is actually defined as $\argmax_t f$. So this is why I have proposed above iterative approach, however I cannot see how this must converge or if there is a better approach.

Comment: @Marekkk The comment section is not the place to formulate the problem. Please update your question. You don't pay extra tax for each edit you make.  There are no answers yet, so you're not breaking anyone's work.